# All-pass filter implementation in numpy

Tags: python, allpass

I'm playing with Python & numpy to filter audio. It is relatively straightforward to design and us low-high-bandpass/stop FIR and IIR filters, stuff can be done in a couple of lines.

I'm implementing a small software defined radio software, and I need an all-pass filter that has 90 degrees phase shift everywhere, and is flat (as much as possible).

Unfortunately I was unable to find any quick solution for this.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thank you,

Tamás.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.stackexchange. This site can help you if you need to answer a question of _how_ or _why_ something works, or do not understand a _concept_, help you devise an _algorithm_ from the domain if signal processing. What you're looking for is more _programming_ - maybe you should flag your own question and request it be moved to stackoverflow.com , it might be more suitable there. Also, try providing the information about what you have tried and which precise part gives you problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hilbert transform will produce a signal with 90 degree phase shift.  Look in Numpy documentation at [scipy.signal.hilbert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) as a start.

I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do, but you mentioned 90 degree phase shift and radio in the same post, so you may find the following article of use:

[http://home.comcast.net/~szemengtan/LinearSystems/hilbert.pdf](http://home.comcast.net/%7Eszemengtan/LinearSystems/hilbert.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Bruce, I missed this part. I'll check the docs.

Comment: Yepp, Mr. Hilbert solved my Problem. To put it into python: numpy.imag(scipy.signal.hilbert( <signal array> ))

Comment: Note that `hilbert` actually computes the analytic signal, you have to take the imaginary part to get the actual hilbert transform.  This is copied from Matlab